# Declaring Lua Functions and referencing with correct name

Tags: lua

What is the difference between the following Lua scripts in terms of function scope. How would it effect the need to `require 'calculator'` in some other Lua script. And how would it be referenced in say a `LuaState.getGlobal(function_name)`. What would be its proper function name?  Also any comment on advantages/disadvantages of the declaration approaches.

A) Calculator.lua

```
function foo(n) 
   return n+1;
end
```

B) Calculator.lua

```
calc= {}
function calc.foo(n) 
  return n+1;
end
```

C) Calculator.lua

```
function foo(n) 
   return n+1;
end
function calculator()
   calc = {}
   calc.foo=foo
   return calc
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what it is you mean exactly by the "scope" of these scripts. Exactly what these scripts do depends on how they're being executed. You could give them a different environment, thus changing what they think of as "globals".

So, I will explain what each of these scripts does based on the assumption that you are loading them with `dofile`, `dostring`, or something of the like. That is, you're applying them to the global environment.

A)

This creates a single global variable, `foo`, which is a function.

B)

This creates a single global variable, `calc`, which is a *table*. This table has a single entry, with the key `foo`, who's value is a function.

C)

This creates *two* global variables. `foo` is a function. `calculator` is also a function. Each call to `calculator` will cause the global variable `calc` to be overwritten. The new value of `calc` will be a table that has a single entry, with the key `foo`, who's value is a copy of what is stored in the global variable `foo`.

It's hard to say what the "advantages" of method **C** are, since it makes no sense. It creates two functions instead of one, and that second function keeps creating new tables.

**B** is just a "namespace" scoped version of **A**. The general expectation with Lua modules is that including them will usually create some table that will contain all of the functions in that module, to avoid name conflicts with existing global state. In that regard, **B** may be better. But it depends mostly on what this script will be used for.

Personally, for simple shell scripts and utility scripts, I don't bother with proper module scoping. When I do make a proper module, I generally use the [`module`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-module) Lua function.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer, but a comment on semantics - in Lua, you do not **declare** a function, you **create** it. The function becomes available at the time the `function(...) ... end` is executed. How it is available depends on where you store it.

You have to remember that:

```
function myfun(foo) print('foo') end
```

is just syntactic sugar for:

```
myfun = function(foo) print('foo') end
```

If you do not do anything special, `myfun` becomes a global variable stored in the global state (accessible through `_G`). If you say `local myfun` before actually calling `function myfun() end`, the function (actually a [*closure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)) will be stored in the local variable and available only to the scope of the local variable.

If you use `require`, it just finds the file and loads it once. It doesn't do anything fancy with the module like hiding globals, etc. So if you write `function foo() end` in your module `Calculator.lua`, then calling `require 'Calculator'` will create a function in global `foo`, which you can access using `LuaState.getGlobal("foo")`. If you create a table of functions (step **B**), you have to use 2 steps:

```
L.getGlobal("calc")   -- pushes the "calc" global (a table) to the stack
L.getField(-1, "foo") -- gets the "foo" field from the table
```